# Python: How do I usefully unittest a method invoking OptionParser?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, optionparser

In my Python Unit Tests (via standard nosetests / unittest.TestCase) I have a class where I've created a method that does option parsing.  I would like to write a nice unit testing routine that exercises it nicely.

More than that, with 4 questions below, I'm looking for the **OPTIMAL** way to do this. ... ?

```
from optparse import OptionParser

class Something(object):

    def getOptionParser(self):
        return OptionParser()

    def parseMyOptions(self):
        parser = self.getOptionParser()
        parser.add_option('--debug',    action='store_true', help='Run debug mode.')
        parser.add_option('--logfile',  default='log/logfile.log', help='what filename')
        parser.add_option('--url',      type='string', help='desired url')
        (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
        self.debug          = options.debug
        self.logfile        = options.logfile
        self.url            = options.url

    def main(self):
        self.parseMyOptions()

class MockOptionParser(object):
      def __init__(self):
          self.url = None
          self.debug = None
          self.logfile = None
      def add_option(self, *args, action=None, help=None, default=None):
          pass
      def parse_args(self):
          pass
      def error(self):
          pass

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        s = Something()
        s.getOptionParser = MockOptionParser()
        s.parseMyOptions()
        assert True, "assert something useful?"
```

So the problems here are:

1. What useful thing can I assert?
2. How do I auto-generate MockOptionParser without reproducing the skeleton of OptionParser?

Notice that in MockOptionParser's add_option, I DON'T handle 'type' keyword, but I should.  I'm sure I won't predict all the methods and keyword args that OptionParser uses and implement them in MockOptionParser.  **Is there a simpler way?**

1. Initializing MockOptionParser with self vars for each option is UGLY.  is there a way to do this nicely?
2. Is there an easy way to verify all the add_option() vars (options.debug, for instance) are used to set something like self.debug?

Comment: What are you getting out of MockOptionParser? Does it do other things? From what I can see all you are doing here is testing the mock object, which seems somewhat futile.

Comment: In python3 you can use `unittest.mock` to avoid defining `MockOptionParser` by hand. If you are using python2 you can download the module from PyPI. Anyway I think you should concentrate more on testing the logic of your program instead of checking that you use `OptionParser` correctly.